# Ruby on Rails: obtaining iOS device identifiers from .mobileconfig in Safari

Tags: ios, iphone, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using **Ruby on Rails** I want to obtain iOS device identifiers by serving a .mobileconfig xml file.

[This tutorial](http://www.joshwright.com/tips/getting-an-iphone-udid-from-mobile-safari) and others instruct how to accomplish this in php.

Here are my steps thus far:

1.) .mobileconfig

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PayloadContent</key>
    <dict>
        <key>URL</key>
        <string>https://mywebsite.com/retrieve</string>
        <key>DeviceAttributes</key>
        <array>
            <string>UDID</string>
            <string>IMEI</string>
            <string>ICCID</string>
            <string>VERSION</string>
            <string>PRODUCT</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
    <string>mywebsite.com</string>
    <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
    <string>Profile Service</string>
    <key>PayloadVersion</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>PayloadUUID</key>
    <string>9CF421B3-9853-4454-BC8A-982CBD3C907C</string>
    <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.mywebsite.profile-service</string>
    <key>PayloadDescription</key>
    <string>This temporary profile will be used to find and display your current device's UDID.</string>
    <key>PayloadType</key>
    <string>Profile Service</string>
</dict>
```

2.) Direct user to www.mywebsite.com/install. Route as follows:

```
get 'install', to: 'users#install_profile'
```

3.) Serve .mobileconfig file (located in public folder), making sure to set the MIME type to application/x-apple-aspen-config

```
def install_profile
  render file: Rails.root.join("public", "Profile.mobileconfig"), layout: false, content_type: "application/x-apple-aspen-config"
end
```

The Installing Profile opens on iOS device and the user is able to select "Install" > "Install now". They are then redirected to the URL specified in the xml (i.e., https://mywebsite.com/retrieve).

However, this is done as a **GET** with no apparent params.

I believe this is suppose to be a POST.

Below are some references to the OTA Profile Delivery and Configuration.

I would greatly appreciate any advise, and hopefully this can serve as reference for other ruby developers stuck on this issue.

[Reference documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/networkinginternet/conceptual/iphoneotaconfiguration/Introduction/Introduction.html)

[Profile Delivery Concepts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/networkinginternet/conceptual/iphoneotaconfiguration/OTASecurity/OTASecurity.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009505-CH3-SW1)

[Configuration Profile Example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/networkinginternet/conceptual/iphoneotaconfiguration/ConfigurationProfileExamples/ConfigurationProfileExamples.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009505-CH4-SW1)

Comment: Not sure of the root cause; but I have working code on GitHub. https://github.com/AppBlade/TestHub/blob/master/app/controllers/devices_controller.rb Feel free to take a peak.

Comment: It should indeed be a post. What's your route file look and log look like?